# Which is the encoding of the default .xdy file

Tags: input-encodings, xindy

In order to create my own system of group letter with `xindy`, I am looking to the default files. For examples the files `xindy/modules/lang/french/utf8.xdy`.

But ... I am not able to know which is the encoding used, and so, which are the letters group defined ...

Comment: What do you mean? UTF8 is the encoding...

Comment: now, the files are not encoded in utf8...

Comment: Again, what do you mean? That file is designed for use with the UTF8 encoding. Hence the name.

Comment: What can I say more ? The file is calle "utf8" BUT it is not encoded in utf8. Try to open it with any uft8 editor...

Comment: So is the problem that you cannot open the file? You could try saying so!

Comment: I can open it, but I have no readable charatcters...

Comment: None at all? I mean, `less` can't display all of the characters, but most of it is readable. (Maybe the crucial characters are not - I didn't look closely.)

Comment: I assume you've read alphabets-doc and texindy?

Comment: yes I read. And don't help me. Yes, the crucial characters, the one which I need to look to change their order or somehting like this, are not readable.

Comment: I guess I would try to track down a copy of `make-rules.pl` and see what it does. (It is frustrating that the source of generated files is often missing.)

Answer (score 2):

It's not obvious from the docs, but the files in `xindy/modules/lang` are generated from source files (ending in `.pl.in`), which are not included in the distribution. Specifying an alternative alphabet is not conceptually difficult, but it's a long process. You'll need to get the `xindy-make-rules` package from [xindy.org](http://www.xindy.org/). [This answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/240791/xindy-doesnt-sort-keywords-properly/241708#241708) explains the rest of the process.